# Error al incluir una función de cadenas en un menú en c

Tags: c, funciones, switch

mi pregunta es que desarrollé una función que cuenta cuantas veces aparece una palabra dentro de una oración (ambas introducidas por teclado), el problema es que al incluir dicha función en una sentencia switch deja de funcionar correctamente es decir se salta líneas de comando, y solo es dentro de esa sentencia porque por fuera de esta, el código funciona bien.
adjunto el codigo de la funcion:

```
void Palabra_Iterativa(){
    char Palabra[15];

    char vecFrase[200];
    char *Tok;
    int Contador=0;
    printf("Palabra Iterativa\n\n");
    printf("\nEscriba la frase a analizar: \n");
    gets(vecFrase);
    printf("Escriba la palabra que desea buscar: \n");
    gets(Palabra);
    fflush(stdin);
    
    Tok= strtok (vecFrase, " ,.:;");
    while(Tok!=NULL){
        if (stricmp(Tok, Palabra)==0){
            Contador++;
        }
        Tok=strtok(NULL," ,.:;");
    }
    printf(" La palabra %s se encontro %d veces",Palabra,Contador);
    printf("\n");
}
```

Como dije al ponerlo dentro de un switch que uso como opciones de un menú, se salta el primer gets y me envía directamente al segundo por lo que no hace nada. muchas gracias por la ayuda!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seguro que en el `switch` en cuestión estás leyendo algo con `scanf()`.

Esa función lee hasta el retorno de carro **pero no lee el retorno de carro** que queda a la espera de ser leido en el buffer de entrada. Si haces otro `scanf()` no lo notarás, pues se saltará ese retorno de carro cuando lo encuentre, pero en cambio en tu caso llamas a la función `Palabra_Iterativa()`, la cual dentro tiene un `gets()`.

La función `gets()` lee del buffer de entrada hasta encontrar un retorno de carro, y te devuelve todo lo que haya leido hasta ese punto. En este caso en particular lo primero que se encuentra es el retorno de carro que dejó allí el anterior `scanf()`, por lo que inmediatamente da la línea por terminada y te retorna una línea vacía.

Cuando lo tenías sin el switch te funcionaba porque el `gets()` era la primera operación de lectura de la entrada estándar realizada por tu programa y en ese momento el buffer de entrada estaba vacío, por lo que `gets()` se quedaba esperando a que apareciera algo. En cambio en el nuevo escenario ya encuentra algo (un retorno de carro) por lo que no tiene que esperar.

Una posible solución es hacer un `getch()` justo tras el `scanf()` para así "consumir" un carácter que será el retorno de carro que `scanf()` había dejado sin leer.

### Otras observaciones

- No hagas `fflush(stdin)`. La operación sólo tiene sentido sobre flujos de salida y no sobre flujos de entrada.
- No se recomienda usar `gets()` sino `fgets()` debido a que la primera leerá una línea completa *sin tener en cuenta lo larga que pueda ser*. Si la línea tuviera más de 200 caracteres (que es el espacio que tienes reservado para su lectura), `gets()` leería de todas formas más, produciendo un *buffer overrun*. Usando `fgets()` puedes limitar el número de caracteres a leer: `fgets(vecFrase, 200, stdin)`

Comment: Hice todo lo que me dijiste y la verdad es que entendí el problema con la explicación que me diste, con getch() no me sirvió pero busque y en lugar de getch() le agregue justo después del scanf() un getchar() y ya soluciono el problema. ¿crees que haya algún efecto si lo uso así?. y otra cosa el fgets() solo con vecFrase o ambos?, y sobre todo muchas gracias porque me fue de gran ayuda y entendí bien el error.

Comment: La recomendación de cambiar `gets()` por `fgets()` es generica. Evita siempre `gets()` porque no tiene forma de limitar el número de letras leídas. Y en cuanto a `getchar()` tienes razón, siempre los confundo.

Comment: Entiendo, muchas gracias llevaba estancado un largo rato en esto pero ya pude hacer que funcionara gracias a ti, te agradezco infinitamente.